# How can I enter the elements of my list into a string with a use of loop?

Tags: python, string, list

please see my code below,

```
example_list = [
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['f','g','h'],
    ['i','j','k'],
]

my_string = '''

'''
for s in example_list:
    pass #what will write?

print(my_string)
```

#ouput should be a 3 line string just like this,

```
('a','b','c'), 
('f','g','h'), 
('i','j','k');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
example_list = [
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['f','g','h'],
    ['i','j','k'],
]

my_string = '''

'''
for s in example_list:
  my_string = my_string +  str(tuple(s))  + ',\n'
my_string = my_string.strip(',\n') + ';'

print(my_string)
```

Output:

```
('a', 'b', 'c'),
('f', 'g', 'h'),
('i', 'j', 'k');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn each of the sublists into tuples and then the individual strings, then use `str.join` to create a string with `\n` between them.

```
example_list = [
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['f','g','h'],
    ['i','j','k'],
]

s = '\n'.join([str(tuple(i)) for i in example_list])
print(s)
```

```
('a', 'b', 'c')
('f', 'g', 'h')
('i', 'j', 'k')
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code:::::::::::

```
example_list = [
['a','b','c'],
['f','g','h'],
['i','j','k'],
]

my_string = ''
for s in example_list:
    if example_list[-1] == s:
        my_string += str(tuple(s))+';'
    else:
        my_string += str(tuple(s))+',\n'
print(my_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `tuple(s)`

Here is the code

```py
example_list = [
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['f','g','h'],
    ['i','j','k'],
]

for s in example_list:
    a=tuple(s)
    print(a)
```

**Output**

```
('a', 'b', 'c')
('f', 'g', 'h')
('i', 'j', 'k')
```